# angular4- show element only when texbox is focused

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to show an element on my page when a textbox is focused.

HTML

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-row >
        <ion-col>
          <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search Account Number" [(ngModel)]="searchInput"> </ion-searchbar>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>
          <ion-icon (click)="searchCustomer()" ion-item name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <p align="right" *ngIf="searchInput.length > 0">
        <span style="color:gray;padding:5px">Switch to Advance Search</span>
      </p>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

JavaScript

```
export class AppHomePage {

  searchInput: any;
  searchResults: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController,
              public http: Http,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

              this.searchResults = [];
  }
}
```

With my script when the page loads i get this error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: something to do with searchInput it seems.  Could you please share your component code?

Comment: In your `.ts` do `searchInput = ''` it is probably not initialized. But what you are doing isn't showing the `p` element when the `input` is focused. It will show only when the user type something.

Comment: Give searchInput type any

Comment: If you want something to happen when you focus an input, I suggest using the `focus` event to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: 
 If you haven't initialised `seachInput = ''` then do it first.

Option 2: User `(input)` event and get length when user enter any data into text box.

```
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Search Account Number" (input)="getSeachData($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchInput"> </ion-searchbar>
```

In your `.ts` file.

```
// First set variable above constructor. 
searchFlag : boolen = false;
getSeachData(event){
   this.searchFlag = true ? event.target.value.length > 0 : false;
}
```

In your `HTML` file.

```
<p align="right" *ngIf="searchFlag">
    <span style="color:gray;padding:5px">Switch to Advance Search</span>
</p>
```

In this way you can do what you want. But Still I suggest to go with the `first` option. If it's not work well then go with `second` option.

Hope for the best.

Comment: its only allowing one character in the textbox

Comment: You mean when you go with `option 2` it allows only one character in textbox ?

Comment: i mean with this answer

Comment: @user6579134 I have update my answer. Please try with my updated answer.

Comment: its now allowing multiple but when you clear the textbox still the advance search region shows

Comment: Yes, because when you enter any text the flag will true. But if you want to to hide when you reset text then the simple way is to go with string's length.

Comment: @user6579134 I have update my answer again with fixed your reset text issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180957/discussion-between-user6579134-and-sachin-shah).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ionFocus` event to achieve what you want.

HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-row >
        <ion-col>
          <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search Account Number" [(ngModel)]="searchInput"> </ion-searchbar>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>
          <ion-icon (click)="searchCustomer()" (ionFocus)="showSwitchAdvanceSearch()" ion-item name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <p align="right" *ngIf="showSwitchAdvanceSearch">
        <span style="color:gray;padding:5px">Switch to Advance Search</span>
      </p>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Typescript

```
export class AppHomePage {

  searchInput: any;
  searchResults: any;
  showSwitchAdvanceSearch = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController,
              public http: Http,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

              this.searchResults = [];
  }

  showSwitchAdvanceSearch() {
    this.displaySwitchAdvanceSearch = true;
  }
}
```